# Laravel - dd() is not working in Maatwebsites import

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have Maaetwebsites-3.1 in Laravel-5.8 for Excel Import:

```
use App\Imports\GradesImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

public function gradeForm()
{               
    return view('hr.grades.import_grade_form');
} 

public function importGradeLevel(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|max:10000|mimes:xlsx,xls',
    ]);

  $path1 = $request->file('file')->store('import'); 
  $path=storage_path('app').'/'.$path1;  

  
        $import = new GradesImport;
        $import->import($path); 
        dd($import->errors());

        Session::flash('success', 'Grade Records Imported Successfully');
        return redirect()->route('hr.grades.index');              
}
```

Then this is the Excel Import

Import:

```
class LevelImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, SkipsOnError, WithValidation, WithBatchInserts
{  
   use Importable, SkipsErrors;

   public function model(array $row)
   {  
      $grade_data = [
        'grade_level_code'                  => $row['grade_code'] ?? '',
        'grade_level_name'                  => $row['grade_name'] ?? '',
     ];         
    
    $grade = Grade::create($grade_data);              
}
```

I observed that it's not seeing the:

> dd($import->errors());

Why and How do  resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: how are you calling `importGradeLevel` ?

Comment: dumps usually won't work inside a streamed response callback. If nothing else, you can always \Log::info() what you want